# Get records based on latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In the below query I need to take only one record which is the latest phDate.

```
 WITH TEMP_PAT_PIP_AddedBy
AS (
    SELECT S.ppId
        ,(
            SELECT PersonID
            FROM [PFMADestination].[dbo].PERSON
            WHERE SourceType = 'user_Users'
                AND SourceId = S.uuId
            ) AS AddedByToStore
        ,phDate
    FROM [PFMADestination].[dbo].PatientPIP D
    INNER JOIN [PFMAOldProd].[dbo].pat_History S ON S.ppId = D.PatientId
        AND phEvent = 'PIP-info uppdaterad'
    )
--select * from TEMP_PAT_PIP_AddedBy order by ppId, phDate desc
UPDATE P
SET AddedBy = ISNULL(AddedByToStore, 1), Date=phDate
FROM TEMP_PAT_PIP_AddedBy T
INNER JOIN [PFMADestination].[dbo].[PatientPIP] P ON T.ppId = P.PatientId
```

**Expected Output for CTE** Take only latest phDate for each ppId and ignore other if its more than 1 record then update it.

[image]

Comment: ...where phDate = (select max(phDate) from TEMP_PAT_PIP_AddedBy where ppId = TEMP_PAT_PIP_AddedBy.ppId)

Comment: @jarlh, I want to make this change in CTE itself. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using partition by clause you can get expected output. Try following query :

```
WITH TEMP_PAT_PIP_AddedBy
AS (
    SELECT S.ppId
        ,(
            SELECT PersonID
            FROM [PFMADestination].[dbo].PERSON
            WHERE SourceType = 'user_Users'
                AND SourceId = S.uuId
            ) AS AddedByToStore
        ,phDate , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY S.ppId ORDER BY phDate DESC) AS NUM
    FROM [PFMADestination].[dbo].PatientPIP D
    INNER JOIN [PFMAOldProd].[dbo].pat_History S ON S.ppId = D.PatientId
        AND phEvent = 'PIP-info uppdaterad'
    )

UPDATE P
SET AddedBy = ISNULL(AddedByToStore, 1), Date=phDate
FROM TEMP_PAT_PIP_AddedBy T
INNER JOIN [PFMADestination].[dbo].[PatientPIP] P 
ON T.ppId = P.PatientId AND T.NUM=1
```

Comment: Can I make this i CTE itself?

Comment: Yes , you need to apply Num=1 filter within CTE in that case.

Comment: I have updated my question with actual need. The CTE will be used in update statement

Comment: Updated ans. In that case you just need to put one element in join T.NUM = 1

Answer (score 1):

Add phDate = max phDate condition to the where clause:

```
WITH TEMP_PAT_PIP_AddedBy
AS (
    SELECT S.ppId
        ,(
            SELECT PersonID
            FROM [PFMADestination].[dbo].PERSON
            WHERE SourceType = 'user_Users'
                AND SourceId = S.uuId
            ) AS AddedByToStore
        ,phDate
    FROM [PFMADestination].[dbo].PatientPIP D
    INNER JOIN [PFMAOldProd].[dbo].pat_History S ON S.ppId = D.PatientId
        AND phEvent = 'PIP-info uppdaterad'
    )
SELECT *
FROM TEMP_PAT_PIP_AddedBy
where phDate = (select max(phDate) from TEMP_PAT_PIP_AddedBy
                where ppId = TEMP_PAT_PIP_AddedBy.ppId) 
ORDER BY ppId
    ,phDate DESC
```

Edited version, is phDate a P column? (If not, edit my answer.)

```
 WITH TEMP_PAT_PIP_AddedBy
    AS (
        SELECT S.ppId
            ,(
                SELECT PersonID
                FROM [PFMADestination].[dbo].PERSON
                WHERE SourceType = 'user_Users'
                    AND SourceId = S.uuId
                ) AS AddedByToStore
            ,phDate
        FROM [PFMADestination].[dbo].PatientPIP D
        INNER JOIN [PFMAOldProd].[dbo].pat_History S ON S.ppId = D.PatientId
            AND phEvent = 'PIP-info uppdaterad'
            AND phDate = (select max(phDate) from P
                          where ppId = P.ppId)
        )
    --select * from TEMP_PAT_PIP_AddedBy order by ppId, phDate desc
    UPDATE P
    SET AddedBy = ISNULL(AddedByToStore, 1), Date=phDate
    FROM TEMP_PAT_PIP_AddedBy T
    INNER JOIN [PFMADestination].[dbo].[PatientPIP] P ON T.ppId = P.PatientId
```

Svensk?

Comment: I have updated my question with actual need. The CTE will be used in update statement

Comment: @Billa, have now added another query which may help you.